# What other known characters were Divergent in the Divergent series?

Tags: divergent

I know Uriah, Tris, not Tobias, he was just "the appearance," yes that little girl, the boy that died when Eric shot him in the elevator lobby or something, and I feel like I am missing someone.
Also, as it is impossible for Caleb to be only a few months older than Tris, are they twins? And would that, in turn, make Caleb Divergent?
Cause you see, pregnancy lasts about forty weeks, and that is way more than a few months.

Comment: Another thing to consider are the Factionless — it's possible that many divergent people are Factionless. They don't fit into one Faction and so they're outcasts. Especially in the movies, we see a lot of Factionless people but most of them are not identified by name. So by "known characters," do you mean named/identified characters?

Comment: Yes. Known means named or individually identified, like the boy that Eric killed.

Comment: I honestly thought that that was widely known.

Comment: Maybe I'm splitting hairs, so, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer for how many known characters are divergent, but I can answer the second part about the age difference between Caleb and Tris.

We know Caleb and Tris are a little less than a year apart.

> "Caleb is not quite a year older than I am, so we are in the same year
>   at school." Divergent Chapter 1

Their mom could have had them both in a short time.

Women who are breastfeeding a newborn are very unlikely to conceive, and most women who aren’t breastfeeding won’t start ovulating again until 6 weeks after giving birth. But it's possible for a woman to ovulate in less time. ([source](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-pregnancy-birth/pregnancy-possible-soon-after-giving-birth-idUSTRE72H6RT20110318))

We don't know details about breastfeeding babies in the Divergent universe, so that aside, it's possible that Natalie Prior gave birth to Caleb and conceived Tris 1-2 months later. Then Tris would have been born 9 months later, making her 10-11 months younger than Caleb.

The dates of Caleb's and Tris's birthdays aren't mentioned in canon, but being almost a year apart and in the same grade in school makes sense if Caleb has a summer birthday and their parents decided to hold Caleb back a year before starting kindergarten (or whatever the first year of school is called in the Divergent universe). I'm also assuming that since they live in Chicago, their school year starts in late August/early September.

Hypothetically, let's say Caleb was born in July and Tris was conceived in September (2 months later). That puts Tris's birthday in June, 11 months younger than Caleb. When Caleb turned 5 in July, his parents decided to hold him back a year for kindergarten. The following year, Tris turned 5 in June, Caleb turned 6 in July, and they started school together, in the same grade, in September.

Why hold Caleb back a year but not Tris? There are a few possibilities, but I think the most likely is because in general, girls tend to mature faster than Caleb. It's possible their parents thought Tris was ready to start school at age 5, even though they didn't send Caleb at age 5. (And Tris being divergent may have also made her cognitive skills mature faster.)

Comment: Holding back? Sound like not Abnegation. He was fit for Erudite, don't you know? It's unlikely. And if it wasn't like that, then Caleb was Divergent, as twins are geneticaly identical.

Comment: @HomuraAkemi Parents may decide to hold their children back for behavioral reasons, too, not just based on intelligence. Caleb being in Erudite means he was smart. Doesn't imply anything about his overall maturity. Also, see my quote above. Caleb and Tris are almost a year apart. Definitely not twins.

Comment: Behavioral reasons don't sound like Abnegation. Like exile.

Comment: Do you not know that divergence is simply awareness during a simulation? That divergentce for them is normalness for us?

Comment: Also, the story says that Caleb is only a few months older. That raises questions.